# Is the enlightened badge not awarded on self answers?

Tags: discussion, badges

A couple of days back, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19562199/1860929) on [get all keys set in memcached](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19560150/1860929) got 10 votes, which is a question I had asked. I got the [nice answer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=1860929) for it, but didn't get the enlightened badge, even though mine is the only answer.

The enlightened badge description says that it is awarded in the scenario:

> First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Since the description doesn't say so, is the enlightened badge not awarded on self answers?

Comment: Probably because you have complete control over accepting the answer, as well as posting it before anyone else. You have an unfair advantage on self-answers for this badge.

Comment: @Joe Fair point, but the badge description doesn't say that it isn't awarded on self-answering. In any case, I don't have the control on the upvotes (only community does), which means it could be awarded. Hence the question.

Comment: Why so much down vote on this question ? she seem legit

Comment: Voted up because the list of badges in the Help Center ought to either contain complete descriptions or point to the list that has complete descriptions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The full description from [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/158667)

> - silver; awarded multiple times
> - Be the first person to answer a question, and receive a score of at least ten for that answer. The answer must be accepted by the question owner, and **[it mustn't be a self-accept](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/why-didnt-i-earn-another-enlightened-badge/1156#1156)**.